# Unable make table responsive using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have no idea of Bootstrap. Can you guide me how to make one table responsive. how to make this body responsive?

```
    <body style="background-color:#F1F3F6 ">
        <div align="center">
        <h1 style="color:#0083CA;">
            <img src="http://www.kerenel.com/img/banner" alt="Alternate Text" /><br />
            Smart Pond
        </h1>
       <div id="currenttime" style="display:none;">

        </div>
        <table class="">
            <tr>
                <td><div id="water-temperature-container" style="float:left; min-height:400; background-color:red;"></div></td>
                <td><div id="ph-container" style="float:left;background-color:red"></div></td>
                <td><div id="do-container" style="background-color:red"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        Data recorded at Time : <span id="lblDate"></span>


    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Read a Manual: Responsive tables**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)

> Create responsive tables by wrapping any `.table` in `.table-responsive` to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under `768px`). When viewing on anything larger than `768px` wide, you will not see any difference in these tables.

You need to add the following classes:

- `table`
- `table-responsive`

**Code**

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <tr>
    <td><div id="water-temperature-container" style="float:left; min-height:400; background-color:red;" ></div></td>
    <td><div id="ph-container" style="float:left;background-color:red"></div></td>
    <td><div id="do-container" style="background-color:red"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Snippet**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="water-temperature-container" style="float:left; min-height:400; background-color:red;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="ph-container" style="float:left;background-color:red"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="do-container" style="background-color:red"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The **.table-responsive** class creates a responsive table. The table will then scroll horizontally on small devices (*under 768px*). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, there is no difference:

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Aditya</td>
        <td>Singhal</td>
        <td>35</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Indroneil</td>
        <td>Krishnan</td>
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```